# Dynamic table Click checkbox with associated row when checked show value in FORM textfield to edit

Tags: javascript, php, html

Kindly assist. All I want to do is use to checkbox so when 'checked' it shows the data in the fields so a user can edit.

This is my JavaScript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var OS = $("#OS").val();
        var vCPU = $("#vCPU").val();
        var Memory = $("#Memory").val();
        var Val = $("#Val").val();
        var Performance = $("#Performance").val();
        var HighWrite = $("#HighWrite").val();
        var markup 
        = "<tr><td><input class='checkEdit' type='checkbox' name='record'></td><td>" + OS + "</td><td>" + vCPU + "</td><td>" + Memory + "</td><td>" + Val + "</td><td>" + Performance + "</td><td>" + HighWrite + "</td></tr>";

        $("table tbody").append(markup);
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });

});
```

that builds the dynamic table when i fill out the form fields and click the button 'Add' in the image.

Table preview
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Need add click event in checkbox `onclick='handleClick(this);'` make all data input.

in `handleClick` function need toggle input disable base on the checkbox is checked or not.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".add-row").click(function(){
        var OS = $("#OS").val();
        var vCPU = $("#vCPU").val();
        var Memory = $("#Memory").val();
        var Val = $("#Val").val();
        var Performance = $("#Performance").val();
        var HighWrite = $("#HighWrite").val();
        vCPU =10;
        var markup 
        = "<tr><td><input class='checkEdit' type='checkbox' name='record'  onclick='handleClick(this);'></td><td>" +  "<input type='text' class='enable' name='vCPU' value="+vCPU+" readonly>" + "</td></tr>";
$("table tbody").append(markup);

        
    });

    // Find and remove selected table rows
    $(".delete-row").click(function(){
        $("table tbody").find('input[name="record"]').each(function(){
            if($(this).is(":checked")){
                $(this).parents("tr").remove();
            }
        });
    });

});

function handleClick(cb) {
    if(cb.checked){
      $(cb).parent().parent().find(".enable").each(function(){
      console.log($(this));
        $(this).prop('readonly', false);
      });
     }
    else{
        $(cb).parent().parent().find(".enable").each(function(){
        console.log($(this));
          $(this).prop('readonly', true);
      });
    }
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<table>
<tbody></tbody>
</table>

<button class="add-row">add</button>
```

Comment: This doe not do what i want. I just need be able  to see the value show in the from fields when the associated checkbox with row is 'checked'. i ran the code you provide and nothing showed

Comment: @NigelCharles checking

Comment: Basically i just want to edit what was added by using fields above. So when i click the associated check box and row the values show in the fields above where i can make the changes.

Comment: Ok. Nice work however, instead of editing directly in the dynamic table. I would of  really like to edit in the FORM FIELDs above the table when the checkbox is checked which are labeled - Operating  System, No. of vCPU, Memory (GB) etc. I have even made circle in the in the image shared via the link above for you to better understand. One Drive Link:  https://1drv.ms/u/s!AjirY-j2j_YlgZIW2qhnrjWd9vcPOQ

Comment: @NigelCharles I have update coding for FORM FIELDs. If you find it helpful please mark this answer as excepted.Thanks